# jQuery if-request max-width for mediaqueries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I want to use if-requests for my jQuery-functions in my website for special window-widths. This jQuery-functions enable and disable the attribute display of some divs and if the desktop is bigger than 1300pixels it should show all cols instead of only two in the same time. My jQuery functions look like this:

```
function changeCol() {
    var d1= document.getElementById('right-col');
    $(d1).removeClass('hidden');
    $(d1).fadeIn(200);
};
```

The CSS of the cols in 2cols mode are looking like this:

```
.col {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 1.36986301369863%;
   /*width: 31.50684931506849%;*/
   width: 47.93617021276596%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0 1.36986301369863%;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

width: 47.9% is the width for two displayed cols and width: 33.% for three displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that at all.

Use **CSS**:

```
.right-col {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .right-col {
        width: auto;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

That should preserve this `fadeIn` animation.

Here's a little fiddle that I prepared to show you the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/CgwDH/.

Comment: Awesome! I have to admit, that it works really fine in your fiddleJS. The problem is, I have a right column loading dynamically on click while its url changes, without page reload. Is it possible to do this with CSS either? 
Greetings

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. If you want to know how to do that you should learn what is [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or ask a new question. Meanwhile I would be happy if you accepted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I know what AJAX is and my Weppages works, even with - so far. My problem is the same i described at the top. Maybe my formulation in the question was not clear enough - but i need an if-request, which is asking for the width of the page as condition for the function. 
Greetings.

Comment: Ok, just researcher for a time now and your solution seems to be the best. Thumbs up for this.